# Code after await runs twice

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, dapper

i have been developing a Windows form application and for DB end i am using Dapper.
The problem i am trying to solve is to execute a parametered stored procedure asynchronously so that my the execution of the application is not stopped and once the execution is done i should be able to show user a message

This is the function which calls the stored procedure (ExceptionData is not the usual meaning of the word. it has some other meaning in my business logic)

```
    public async Task<bool> Load_ExceptionData(DateTime t)
    {
        IDbTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
            trans = _connection.BeginTransaction();

            DynamicParameters prms = new DynamicParameters();
            prms.Add("Today", t ,DbType.Date);

            await _connection.ExecuteAsync("usp_CC_Load_ExceptionTable",
                                                    prms,
                                                    trans,
                                                    commandTimeout: 0,
                                                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
                                                    );


            trans.Commit();
            return true;                         
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this function is called in trigger to a click

```
    private async void todayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime today;
            today = Convert.ToDateTime("3/16/2016");//DateTime.Today;
            CycleCountRepository _rep = new CycleCountRepository(); // Repository

            todayToolStripMenuItem.Click -= todayToolStripMenuItem_Click; // Disabling the button so while in execution not clicked again

            if (Enabled && _rep.Check_CycleCountToday(today)) // Checks if the data is already present for the date
            {
                todayToolStripMenuItem.Image = Properties.Resources.progress;
                bool result = await _rep.Load_ExceptionData(today); // the async function
                if (result == true)
                {
                    ShowMessage("Data Load Successfully! Date: " + today, "Success", MessageBoxIcon.None); // This message is shown twice
                }
                else
                {
                    ShowMessage("Data Load Error! Date: " + today, "Warning", MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
                CheckTodayLoad();
            }
            else
            {
                ShowMessage("Nothing to Load! No locations scanned today!", "Warning", MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessage(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

    }
```

When i debug the code. the first time execution hits

> await _rep.Load_ExceptionData(today);

it goes back again to the click event start and comes back to the await line.
After that the execution starts and once await is done the message is shown. 
But after showing debugger points to

> if (result == true)
>   line and when i step forward it goes inside it and again Shows the message

I am new to Async/await and this all may just be a dumb mistake i did. But still i will appreciate the answer

Comment: Does the code actually execute twice or does it only appear like that in the debugger. Add messages boxes to make sure.

Comment: @usr Yes it acually runs twice. i get two message boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright guys i have figured out the problem. I will share so that no one else does the same mistake like i did.

So i had a function which was called on form load and was responsible to check whether the data which i am going to load is already present in the table. If "Yes" then remove the click event from the ToolStripMenuItem and if "No" then Add it.

What i was doing wrong was

`todayToolStripMenuItem.Click += todayToolStripMenuItem_Click;`

i was adding it twice to the Click

> - #### One time implicitly it was added in start of the form
>
>   When you click on the control from the design view. It adds its click even in your code and the assign it in the designer of the form
> - #### Second time i was explicitly adding it my self
>
>   check the line in the code

### Solution was to remove the event before adding it to click so that it doesnt add twice

```
    private void CheckTodayLoad()
    {
        DateTime today;
        today = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today); 
        CycleCountRepository _rep = new CycleCountRepository();
        if (_rep.CheckTodayLoaded(today))
        {
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Image = Properties.Resources.checkmark;
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Today " + "[" + today.ToShortDateString() + "]" + " : Loaded";
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Click -= todayToolStripMenuItem_Click;

        }
        else
        {
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Image = SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Today " + "[" + today.ToShortDateString() + "]" + " : Not Loaded";
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Click -= todayToolStripMenuItem_Click; // Just to make sure it is not registered twice. Previously this line wasnt there
            todayToolStripMenuItem.Click += todayToolStripMenuItem_Click;
        }

    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When `await _connection.ExecuteAsync(...)` is executed (because it, most certainly, doesn't complete synchronously), control is returned to the caller (`bool result = await _rep.Load_ExceptionData(today);`) which also returns control to the caller.

When `connection.ExecuteAsync(...)` completes, the continuation of the `Load_ExceptionData` method is posted to the synchronization context.

When `_rep.Load_ExceptionData(today)` completes, the continuation of the `todayToolStripMenuItem_Click` method is posted to the synchronization context.

I'm sure that's what you're seeing.

Comment: yes i think that is what happening. But the question is which of the await is unnecessary and causing this issue. and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that

`todayToolStripMenuItem.Click -= todayToolStripMenuItem_Click;`

Thanks